# Pandas Reduction Error when trying to update dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to update some of the data in my dataframe in the same sense of a update query in SQL.  My current code is as follows:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('filee.csv') # load trades from csv file       

def updateDataframe(row):
    if row['Name'] == "Joe":
        return "Black"
    else:
        return row

df['LastName'] = df.apply(updateDataframe,axis=1)
```

However, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    df['LastName'] = df.apply(updateDataframe,axis=1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2038, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2085, in _set_item
    NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 582, in _set_item
    self._data.set(key, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1459, in set
    _set_item(self.items[loc], value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1454, in _set_item
    block.set(item, arr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 176, in set
    self.values[loc] = value
ValueError: output operand requires a reduction, but reduction is not enabled
```

How do I resolve this.  Or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Please post an example of lines in `filee.csv`.

Comment: Name,LastName
Andy,Blue
Joe,Smith

Comment: try ``df['LastName'] = df.apply(updateDataframe)``, but even better is: ``df.ix[df['LastName']=='Joe','LastName'] = 'Black'``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jeff has a good concise implementation of your problem in the comments above, but if you want to fix the error in your code, try the following:

For the file **filee.csv** with the following contents:

```
Name,LastName
Andy,Blue
Joe,Smith
```

After the else, you need to return a *Last Name* string rather than a row object, as shown below:
    import pandas

```
df = pandas.read_csv('filee.csv') # load trades from csv file       

def updateDataframe(row):
    if row['Name'] == "Joe":
        return "Black"
    else:
        return row['LastName']

df['LastName'] = df.apply(updateDataframe,axis=1)
print df
```

results in the the following output:

```
   Name LastName
0  Andy     Blue
1   Joe    Black
```